# Python: parse gdb.value to bytearray

Tags: python, c, gdb

I try to parse an char[] / char* from gdb.value to bytearray or a list of ints etc.

following test code in c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char img[] = {0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF,
                  0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00,
                  0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF};

    char* imgp = img;
    return 0;
}
```

first try:

```
v = gdb.parse_and_eval("img")
print(v)
l = list(bytearray(v))
```

output:

```
~"\"\\377\\000\\377\\000\\377\\000\\377\\000\\377\\000\\377\\000\\377\\000\\377\\000\\377\\000\\377\\000\\377\\000\\377\\000\\377\\000\\377\"\n"
TypeError: 'gdb.Value' object is not iterable\n"
```

yay a string!?  no gdb.value -> not iterable :( but index able ... ok

```
data = []
for i in range(0, 27):
   data.append(int(v[i]))
```

result:

```
Python Exception <class 'gdb.MemoryError'> Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffc737be000:
```

ok lets do it the "safe" way:

```
 v = gdb.parse_and_eval("img") 
 inferior = gdb.selected_inferior()
 mem = inferior.read_memory(v, 27)
```

result:

```
Python Exception <class 'gdb.MemoryError'> Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffc737be000:
```

Okay whats wrong? How do I get this data out of the gdb.value type?

Comment: What version of gdb are you using, and on what platform? `data = []; 
for i in range(0, 27): data.append(int(v[i]))` works fine for me on gdb 7.10.1, Fedora 23. Could be a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick : GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1

Comment: Hmm. The `data.append(int(v[i]))` loop works for me on that version/platform, too. (64-bit). Do you have any gdb python customizations that could be redefining the way `gdb.Value`s work?

Comment: Is your gdb build with Python 2.7 or 3.x ? Ubuntu uses 3.x there are no other extensions install

Comment: Python 3. I'm using only the software that came with the Ubuntu distro.

Comment: After a clean setup I'm able to read the bytes using the append mehtod but it int(v[i])  maps the values to 0 or -1  not to 337 or something..

Comment: If you declare `img` as `unsigned char[]` instead of `char[]`, `int(v[i])` will be 0 or 255 rather than 0 or -1. If you want to see the data as 377 instead of 255, you can use `"{0:o}".format(int(v[i]))`.